# MariaDB search using REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I am having trouble formulating a valid regular expression for searching in mysql, on a MariaDB database.

I am doing these searches in phpMyAdmin, but will eventually also being doing them in the [Search-Replace-DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) tool (which is also MySQL based).

Let's say the table I am searching is `table-x`, and the field is `field-y`. I need to find the string `\root\localhost/cf/`.

Here's an example of the data that contains this string:

```
O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:4:"file";s:58:"\root\localhost/cf//wp-content/wflogs/config-transient.php";s:4:"hash";s:64:"96e5846450f943eeb94993173c13f1dc28a824eff513d1d8019011515b8729f9";}
```

I tried this regular expression, which works in my expression tester, but doesn't work in MySQL:

`\\root\\localhost/cf/`. The entire query being,

`SELECT * FROM table-x WHERE field-y REGEXP '\\root\\localhost/cf/'`.

This gave me the error, `#1139 - Got error 'PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 6' from regexp`.

To get around the `\l` in my expression, I tried the following:

`SELECT * FROM table-x WHERE field-y REGEXP '\\root\\.ocalhost\/cf\/'`

This works in my reg exp tester. But it gives no results in phpmyadmin. It did get rid of the PCRE error message though.

What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: If this is JSON couldn't you use JSON functions to match this? For regex there's two layers of escaping, SQL and REGEX. As such literal \ can end up as \\\\ in a regex expression. Ugly? yep.

Comment: Thanks. That's just one example of where the string might occur. It's not always in a JSON string. Also, the search / replace is being done in MySQL, so I'll need to stick with that.